# Unix File permission during creation

Tags: linux, unix, file-permissions, user-permissions

How to create a file in UNIX or LINUX from user other than **root** with full permission.

Comment: What is "full permission"?

Comment: @n.m. full permission-rwxrwxrwx or 777  I should get this just after creation.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Create file

```
echo 123 > test.txt
```

Test permissions

```
ls -la test.txt
```

Output +-

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mario mario 4 May  3 14:27 test.txt
```

Change file permissions for all (read, write, execute)

```
chmod 0777 test.txt
```

Test Permissions

```
ls -la test.txt
```

Output +-

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mario mario 4 May  3 14:27 test.txt*
```

About [file system permissions - numeric notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Numeric_notation)